# How to search (using regex) for a regex literal in text?

Tags: regex, vim, escaping

I just stumbled on a case where I had to remove quotes surrounding a specific regex pattern in a file, and the immediate conclusion I came to was to use vim's search and replace util and just escape each special character in the original and replacement patterns.

This worked (after a little tinkering), but it left me wondering if there is a better way to do these sorts of things.

The original regex (quoted): `'/^\//'` to be replaced with `/^\//`

And the search/replace pattern I used:

`s/'\/\^\\\/\/'/\/\^\\\/\//g`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use almost any character as the regex delimiter.  This will save you from having to escape forward slashes.  You can also use groups to extract the regex and avoid re-typing it.  For example, try this:

```
:s#'\(\\^\\//\)'#\1#
```

I do not know if this will work for your case, because the example you listed and the regex you gave do not match up.  (The regex you listed will match `'/^\//'`, not `'\^\//'`. Mine will match the latter. Adjust as necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on grouping in vim's search/replace util - I had tried using the $1 syntax to reference the group which does not work. Also good catch on the regexes not matching up, I mistyped the original and replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Could you avoid using regex entirely by using a nice simple string search and replace?

Comment: Is this possible using vim's search and replace tool for string searches, or is there another tool within vim to do this? Perhaps you can supply a replacement string to fgrep? This could be a good answer, with a few details about the implementation in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this works for you - define the line number before this substitute-expression or place the cursor onto it:

:s:'\(.*\)':\1:

I used vim 7.1 for this. Of course, you can visually mark an area before (onto which this expression shall be executed (use "v" or "V" and move the cursor accordingly)).

Comment: This pattern seems to replace the first ' of any single-quoted string on a given line and leave the trailing ' (vim7.2). Perhaps it has to do with the pattern wanting to greedily match all text between the first and last ' on any line ( try  /'\(.*\)'  ). Regardless, since the expression replaces the first quote of any single-quoted string the only safe way to use this example would be to visually mark each string I wanted to unquote

Comment: I tried the statement from above (which indeed looks odd to me, too) with a vim7.3 that I compiled as given through its unmodified Makefile except from commenting in "CONF_OPT_GUI = --disable-gui" and "CONF_OPT_X = --without-x" because I only use vim on the shell. It really worked also in vim7.3 onto the following input (between " ... "): "The original regex (quoted): '/^\//' to be replaced with /^\//" ...but not on a line containing that input twice or more times on the same line. Please try the following expression: s:'\\(.\{-}\\)':\1:g